# HG: Match remote repo's changesets

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm moving to HG from Git and having a hard time with some of the restrictions HG is imposing on me:

I am in a situation where I have some erroneous commits that I want to blow away. In fact, It would be really nice if I could just match the remote repo's history.

With git, this was easy as pie:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch_name
```

But how can I do it with Mercurial? From what I've heard, moving the 'tip' around can inadvertently spawn off anonymous branches if you don't know what you are doing, which is very different from how git handles the same operation.

Comment: Why switch in the first place? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Equivalent" for what you want is `hg strip` from MQ extension, which you can use to "blow away" your commits.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension

Another "equivalent" is:

```
hg update --clean
```

> With the -C/--clean option, uncommitted changes are discarded and the
>   working directory is updated to the requested changeset.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update

Comment: Your linked page also mentions »If the changeset is not a descendant of the working directory's parent, the update is aborted.«

Comment: @knittl - In Hg, by design, you will not have a clear equivalent. I have also added `hg strip` which will help the OP in his case.

Comment: I'll have to get that extension. Why don't they just package all of this stuff in to begin with...

Comment: @Ben: `strip` is packaged, just disabled. and the reason for that is that it can make inexperienced users easily lose work (although in late versions it backups what it strips)

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution that's often overlooked for blowing away unwanted commits is to simply clone them away:

```
hg clone origin new_clone
rm -rf repo_with_unwanted_commits
```

Now `new_clone` puts you back at the remote repo's tip.  If you've got *other* commits in your clone that you haven't pushed yet, but still want, you can clone locally:

```
hg clone -r tip_you_want repo_with_unwanted_commits new_clone
rm -rf repo_with_unwanted_commits
```

Now `new_clone` contains everything up to the commits you wanted, but excludes the ones you wanted to trash.  In this case, you simply need to setup `[paths]` in `new_clone`'s hgrc to point to the original origin repo and you're back to where you started.

This is easy and requires no extensions, but note that manojlds's suggestion of using `hg strip` will be faster, and you get to keep any untracked files you might have needed.  In either case, this will only work assuming you have not yet pushed the changesets you want to blow away.  If you've already pushed, your only safe option is `hg backout`.

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial for Git users](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts#Command_equivalence_table) has a command equivalence table:

> git reset --hard == hg revert -a --no-backup

Comment: I see the link, but the best equivalent, and in my opinion, is in my answer.

Comment: +1. I see that `hg revert -a` is indeed a good equivalent. Though I think `hg strip` can help OP more in his case.

Comment: As far as I understand, this will only destroy local, *uncommitted* changes.

Answer (score 1):

With Mercurial 1.8 and later you can enable the standard strip extension and do

```
hg strip "outgoing()"
```

This will use a [revset](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) to select the revisions to strip, namely the extra revisions not yet present in the default remote repository.

Comment: +1, +1000 if I could....This should be marked the answer! Other answers point to the extension but don't show how to select un-pushed changesets nicely like this.